# GANTT diagram with conditional formatting (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to do gantt with conditional formatting by list? It's possible?

I have a table where the user selects in the drop-down list if he is on vacation, allowance or on leave, I would like that when selecting for example "vacation" the gantt chart would change to green color. As in the following images:

Drop-down list:

[image: Drop-down list]

GANTT:

[image: GANTT]

Comment: Yes it's possible, Just use a formula that checks if a given day is after the vacation starts and before it ends

Comment: ok, but how could I do that? if the GANTT conditional formatting formula is already: =E(NÃO(ÉCÉL.VAZIA(Cronograma!$D8));Cronograma!$D8<=C$6;Cronograma!$F8>=C$6)

Comment: In the case in the drop-down list are these names: FÉRIAS (
Vacation), ABONO (Allowance) and LICENÇA (License). I wanted to know how I could make it so that as soon as the user puts a vacation in the fields, it goes to green, and if he enters ABONO the gantt turns blue, understand bro?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1733635/edit) instead of adding information in comments. It would also be useful to see the column and row names in your screencaps so we don't need to guess which cells your formulas refer to